# How do I calculate the color and opacity of an transparent overlay given the background and overlayed background?

Tags: colors, overlay, reverse-engineering, background-color, transparent

I'm trying to reverse engineer the colors used in a popular game.

See this low quality screenshot for an example:

[image: Left: #484947 Right: #343737]

The left side is the 'overlayed side' which has the background color and the overlay, and the right side is just the background.

My platform is technically simple HTML & CSS and I use Firefox, but I hope whatever technique I can use will transfer to most platforms.

I looked around on the internet and found 'color blend modes' and 'color mix modes', but I wasn't able to find information on the math behind each of these modes besides the options available.

Additionally, my simple test of see if it was a simple addition problem didn't work either:

```
Given RGBA values X, Y and Z, mix(X, Y) = Z.

X = rgba(32, 34, 35, 1.0)
Y = rgba(124, 123, 123, 0.65)
Z = rgba(93, 92, 93, 1.0)

Test: (X.r)(X.a) + (Y.r)(Y.a) = Z.r
      32 * 1 + 124 * 0.65 = 156.65

We can also rule out that it isn't multiplication, division or any sort of basic operation here.
There's either a non-simple formula or a coefficient being used here that I'm not aware of.
```

I then looked into what Wikipedia had on the subject of blend modes and found an article on [Alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing). It looked to be describing pretty much what I wanted and had equations for me. I developed a little python script to see if it would work, but it didn't.

```py
from typing import List

class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, r: float, g: float, b: float, a: float = 1.0) -> None:
        self.r, self.g, self.b, self.a = r, g, b, a

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Color({self.r}, {self.g}, {self.b}, {self.a:.2%})'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()

def mix(a: Color, b: Color) -> Color:
    Ao = a.a + (b.a * (1 - a.a))
    Co: List[float] = []

    for Ca, Cb in zip([a.r, a.g, a.b], [b.r, b.g, b.b]):
        pre = (Ca + a.a) + ((Cb * b.a) * (1 - a.a))
        Co.append(pre  / Ao)
    
    return Color(r=Co[0], g=Co[1], b=Co[2], a=Ao)


bg = Color(32, 34, 35)
overlay = Color(124, 123, 123, 0.65)
c = mix(overlay, bg)

# Color(32, 34, 35, 100.00%) + Color(124, 123, 123, 65.00%) = Color(135.85, 135.55, 135.9, 100.00%)
print(f'{bg} + {overlay} = ')
print(c)
```

Given these two colors, how would I determine what would be a suitable overlay I could use to reach the same 'overlayed' color? I assume there would be a very large number (but not infinite, as long as we're using integers and integer percentages).

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The math for performing an alpha blend is listed in the CSS spec.

## Longer Answer

First:

> `*Given RGBA values X, Y and Z, mix(X, Y) = Z*`

XYZ is a color space, ideally you won't use variables named X,Y, or Z unless you are actually using the XYZ color space, because, confusion...

#### And then this:

```js
Test: (X.r)(X.a) + (Y.r)(Y.a) = Z.r
      32 * 1 + 124 * 0.65 = 156.65 // ????
```

Is ever so close. I'll re-write it to get rid of the XYZ. Also the answer as you wrote it is not 156.65, it's 112.6  Remember PEMDAS, do multiplication before addition. 124 * 0.65 = 80.6 but there's more...

```js
let red = cBG.r * cBG.a + cOver.r * cOver.a;

        32 * 1 + 124 * 0.65 = 112.6
```

What is wrong here is that even though the underlying color has an alpha of 1, it does not contribute that full amount.

The underlying color `cBG` *contributes* the difference of 1 minus the alpha of `cOver`. Since `cOver.a` is 0.65, `cBG.a` is 0.35. Put another way, if the max alpha is 1 (it is) then if color `cOver` contributes 0.77 color `cBG` can only contribute 0.33 — the sum of the alphas must equal 1 (or less) when doing a simple over.

The correct math , when the first color is a solid with alpha 1, is:

```js
let red = cBG.r * (1 - cOver.a) + cOver.r * cOver.a;

      32 * 0.35 + 124 * 0.65 = 91.8
```

If both colors have an alpha less than 1, the math is a little more complicated—simplest is to always start with a color with an alpha of 1 and then build upwards.